# node: Get dependencies licence

Tags: node.js, npm, licensing

I am writing a node application. In my application, I would like to ask use `npm package name` (in front end) send to node server and receive the licence of  that package. Up to now, the only way I have found is to use `npm view`, but would like something that can be used programmatically. Is there any `npm package` that can help to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are many ways to get info about dependencies. The best way I finally found is https://www.npmjs.com/package/npmview. It is and awesome tool and well documented.